# kohana dynamic uri routing to redirect to a controller function

Tags: kohana, custom-routes

I have to write a route in kohana for the following

```
$this->request->redirect("/" . input::post('custom_url'));
```

example if the custom_url = testpage
then it should be 'abc.com/testpage' and it should be redirected to a controller function example contoller/profile.

example if the custom_url = testpage1
then it should be 'abc.com/testpage1'

```
Route::set('event', '(event(/<url>))')
  ->defaults(array(
    'controller' => 'event',
    'action' => 'profile',
  ));
```

my url will be domainname/event/customname and it should redirect to event/profile. where event is controller and profile is action

Comment: What exactly is your question/why can't you do what you're planning to do?

Comment: ever found a solution for this one? I'm looking for something similar to this too.